# Extracting value from xml attribute using digester3 pattern

Tags: java, apache-commons-digester

Having xml:

```
<root>
  <person id = "123"/>
</root>
```

Bean mapping:

```
public class Root {
    private Person person;
    public void setPerson(Person person) ...
}

public class Person {
    String id;
    public void setId(String id) ...
}
```

I have no idea, **how** can to implement `digester3`'s **pattern** for setting `id` of `Person` class using its **setter** (`setId(String id)`) in such style:

```
new AbstractRulesModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            forPattern("root").createObject().ofType(Root.class);    
            forPattern("root/person").createObject().ofType(Person.class).then().setNext("setPerson");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **callMethod()** and **callParam()**. Your code would be something like this:

```
new AbstractRulesModule() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        forPattern("root").createObject().ofType(Root.class);
        forPattern("root/person").createObject().ofType(Person.class).then()
                .callMethod("setId").withParamCount(1).then()
                .callParam().ofIndex(0).fromAttribute("id").then()
                .setNext("setPerson");
        }
}
```

You can consult the [javadoc of digester3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/digester3) to have a better idea.